# Implementing led lighting with SR-ZG9101FA-RGBW

Tags: led, wiring, led-strip, zigbee

So I have this device: [SR-ZG9101FA-RGBW](https://www.sunricher.com/constant-voltage-rgbw-zigbee-led-lighting-device-sr-zg9101fa-rgbw.html)

I'm trying to properly connect it, but so far I'm having issues such as being unable to detect device in philips hue app and only two color channels are being powered.

This might have to do something with the fact, that I only used single V+ and V- connectors to power device, but device seems to have two of them!

Can anyone explain why does it need to have two V+ and two V- connectors for power input?

Can I use same 12V power source for both of these connectors? If so, can I just split + and - wires in two and then connect?

P. S. I have very little knowledge of electrical wiring, so bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have only connected power to one pair of (V+ & V-) terminals is not the problem as both of the *V+* are connected to each other and the same applies to both *V-* terminals.

The device has two pair of terminals for daisy chaining multiple led drivers.

Take a look at this:

[image]

(Image [Source](https://www.sunricher.com/constant-voltage-rgbw-zigbee-led-lighting-device-sr-zg9101fa-rgbw.html))

I would recommend you to do some more research on the product page and contact the manufacturer regarding your issues.

Comment: So it doesn't really matter which V+ and V- terminal combinations I use? Their tech support is not responding to any of my emails and the shop where I bought it also doesn't give me any information on what might be wrong or things that I should try.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't really may matter which V+ and V- terminal combinations you use. Have you followed there tutorial [video](https://youtu.be/EJYJleNRTEQ) correctly. Make sure that your connections are right and you are using power supply of adequate amperage and voltage.

Comment: Well on the device itself it has something like lin=20.5A. And my current test power source says only 1.2A. But I only do testing with 10cm of LED strip. Does that mean the device handles this much current and only outputs as much as needed? Sorry if the questions sound stupid, still trying to figure out how all of this work.

Comment: Originally this device was already installed in my room with power source of 22Amps, but it was still showing only purple which was a mix of blue and red, ignoring green and white channels.

Comment: Please provide a link or citation for the graphic in your answer. Where did you get it?

Comment: @SMGhost, In that case the led driver might be faulty or might not be getting proper signals from Phillips Hue app.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, Got it from the product page linked by SMGhost, added the link.

Comment: @SMGhost, Also, do insure the correct led strips are being used.

Comment: Even without philips hue the controller is supposed to light up to provide visual indication of pairing, so probably I'll have to get another one.

Comment: I use RGBW led strips, which were recommended for me in the same shop to work with this controller.